# "eclipse Could not save master table to file"

Tags: eclipse

I have my eclipse telling about every 10 minutes that "eclipse Could not save master table to file".

I found an old discusion on this, which tells to delete `/home/<username>/.eclipse` folder, but I did a search and there's no such folder in my whole system.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If /home/<username>/.eclipse is doesn't exist they probably mean the folder where you have installed eclipse. I have found some other file that bugged me there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting correct privileges to the file

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources`
```

I would suggest setting correct permissions for the whole workspace

See [discussion here](http://code.google.com/p/mosync/issues/detail?id=785#c3)

Comment: It was solved with another eclipse version. I hadn't try your solution, but would probably work.. or not.. anyway.. :)

Comment: Vadim your link doesn't work...

Comment: @Kibi, I've updated the link

Comment: Thanks @VadimRutkovsky - unfortunately the link in the link doesn't work too well, ok, at least I have some place to search from

Answer (score 0):

My `.safetable` file was missing, so I just created it and problem solved.

Comment: Can you explain where this file is, and how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

it's clear from the path reported that .safetable is not a file, but a folder.  I have just hit this issue and created the folder, in the hope that eclipse will create the file with its proper contents next time it tries.  If I don't report back then you may assume this was all that was needed.